# UIButton Transition Curl Up problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Basically, I am trying to UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp a UIButton. The animation 
works perfectly but the button stays there.

i.e. The button curls up, but there is another instance of the button still underneath.

My code as follows:

```
[UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIButton setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIButton setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIButton commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set new button state between `+beginAnimations` and `+commitAnimations` calls. Following code hides clicked button with curl animation:

```
- (void)btnClick:(id)sender{
    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIButton setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIButton setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp 
                                  forView:(UIView*)sender cache:YES];
    ((UIView*)sender).hidden = YES;

    [UIButton commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: That, my friend, was perfect! +1up

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the button (hide the button) when the animation ends.This should be done in

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

which should be set in animation code

like:

```
[UIButton setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: Afraid this still isn't working correctly - I'm obviously missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should of probably checked this before I voted you up...

The button is *still* not dissapearing after the animation has finished :(

My code is now:

```
[UIButton beginAnimations:@"welcomeAnimation" context:nil];
[UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIButton setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(welcomeAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
[UIButton setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIButton setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIButton commitAnimations];
```

and my method:

```
-(void)welcomeAnimationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL *)finished context:(void *)context {
   welcomeButton.hidden = YES;
}
```